# VS code snippets : manage tab order

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

How can I control the tab order in VS code snippets ?
Right now the tab order follow the order of "args" in the Code markup:
comment,access,type,property

I want it to follow the order of declaration in the Declarations:
access,type,property,comment.

I saw samples where they are using $1 instead of $named_var$ but it looks like it's not working : it's only messing my code. $1$ does not mess the code but it does not resolve the issue either.

```
    <Declarations>
        <Literal>
            <ID>access</ID>
            <ToolTip>Accessibilité</ToolTip>
            <Default>public</Default>
        </Literal>          
        <Literal>
            <ID>type</ID>
            <ToolTip>Type de propriété</ToolTip>
            <Default>String</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>property</ID>
            <ToolTip>Nom de la propriété</ToolTip>
            <Default>MyProp</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>comment</ID>
            <ToolTip>Le commentaire</ToolTip>
            <Default>-</Default>
        </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[///<summary>$comment$</summary>
$access$ $type$ $property$ { get; set; }
$end$]]>
    </Code>
```

Comment: I'm interested in this as well :)